# PHP cURL returns 400 on server

Tags: php, curl

I've got a few URL's that are being run through php curl so that I can get the HTTP Code. The funny thing is, some URL's work fine and return 200, but others always return 400. The problem only exist when I feed the URL from the database, if I run it by hardcoding it then it returns 200 as it should.

I've tried urlencoding/decoding and it's not the issue. It looks fine in appearances. The one odd thing that I've been able to find is that the 400 URL's always have a `[content_type] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`. The url's are also really simple `https://sometext.something.something/test` and don't have any parameters

Here's the PHP code i've been running the URL through. It works on my localhost just fine, but on the server it causes issues.

```
function checkStatus($url) {
    $urlencode=urlencode($url);
    foreach (explode('&', $urlencode) as $chunk) {
        $param = explode("=", $chunk);

        if ($param) {
            echo urldecode($param[0]);
            $ch = curl_init(urldecode($param[0]));
        }
    }

    //$ch = curl_init($urlencode);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, true);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8'));
    curl_exec($ch);
    $returnCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $error_report= curl_getinfo($ch);
    print_r($error_report);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $returnCode;
}
```

Here's a sample of the error message:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://url.net/something
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    [http_code] => 400
    [header_size] => 171
    [request_size] => 83
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.056926
    [namelookup_time] => 0.003457
    [connect_time] => 0.004276
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.01614
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.056906
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried using parse_url instead of urlencode / urldecode?

Comment: @Arkadiusz'flies'Rzadkowolski No I haven't. Testing now. EDIT: Well, I'm not really sure how it helps here. It returns the url in the expected format but not much else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL has `https://` that's why it doesn't work for you.

If the data security is not a problem for you, then you can use the following option to use insecure communication for ssl.

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
```

Comment: YES! It worked! Although while messing around with the code, I noticed that if I changed the query to only output 1 url (limit 1) it would return 200 even though it's the same url that returns 400 when select *